# Spark append into sequence file

Tags: java, apache-spark

***How to append more entities into sequence file with `saveAsHadoopFile` in Spark?***

Exception:

> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory
>   hdfs://myhost:8080/data/sequenceFile already exists

Code example:

```
final String path = ...;
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext())
        // itr.next returns `List<Tuple2<String, MyClass>>` where each key is unique in global scope
        .parallelizePairs(itr.next())

        // EXCEPTION: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://myhost:8080/data/sequenceFile already exists
        .saveAsHadoopFile(path, String.class, MyClass.class, SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For work around you can write data in temp Dir and move /rename file into the required Dir
A Rough Sudo would be

```
Outpath =/abc/data/
Tempoutpath = Outpath +"/"+timestamp
move (Tempoutpath/* ,Outpath  )
```